# JQuery selection of TreeNode element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I've been having difficulty selecting the nodes of my IE Web Control TreeView. I'm running the code on IE8 Compatibility Mode (IE7 Standards Mode).

I'm attempting to select the tree nodes like this:

```
$("tvns\\:treenode").css("color", "red");
```

I have tried using this selector both inside a $(document).ready() function and also inside a function which is invoked on pressing a button after the TreeView has been populated. The two \ backspaces are there to escape the colon character.

The TreeView HTML looks like this:

```
<ciswc:TreeView ID="tvWorkArea1" onfocus="fn(this);" 
ondragstart="javascript:captureNode1();" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" 
onclick="fnStoreEID(0)" 
runat="server"SystemImagesPath="Common/webctrl_client/1_0/treeimages/" 
onunhover="unHoverFunction('WorkArea')" EnableViewState="False" 
onhover="selectNode('Smart');" Height="100%" width="100%">
</ciswc:TreeView>
```

I should note that for some reason the TreeView HTML shows up as tvns:TreeView in the IE Developer Tools on running the application. It shouldn't affect the selection of the nodes in the tree though.

Each node looks something like this:

```
<tvns:treenode Expanded="True" Selected="true" NavigateUrl="#" NodeData="0">
New Entity:
</tvns:treenode>
```

When the page initially loads, the TreeView exists, but no tree nodes exist yet. Later after the user has performed some operations, the TreeView will have been populated by the tree nodes.

I have a button which invokes a function which contains the JQuery selector - I have debugged through the javascript and I can see that the code function IS being called, but it doesn't seem to be finding the nodes.

Any ideas?

I have tried selecting the tree nodes using pure javascript, but nothing is returned:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("tvns:treenode");

for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.colour = "red";
}
```

I notice that the HTML has runat="server" attribute. Could this be why I can't select the TreeView nodes?

Comment: Can you post an example of the html generated by the tree? Maybe is just a problem with the selector

Comment: Your JQuery selector hardly corresponds to your html output.

Comment: @SamiRacho, the tree node above *is* an example of HTML generated by the tree. The example I posted above is the first in the tree list. The other tree nodes aren't significantly different.

Comment: @Enam, how does the selector not correspond to the HTML output?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher i was wrong: selector is correct (at least for IE).

Comment: I thought it was aspx, not the html rendered by the browser

Comment: Yes, it's an ASPX page.

Comment: Open internet Explorer Developer tools (F12) and post an example of the html generated on the client. The aspx code you see on visual studio is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have not properly understood how the ASP.NET web server controls work.

The reason I could not select the elements is because they *don't exist in the DOM*, and they never would have. The reason for this is that the IE Web Control I was using (it appears to be an ASP.NET 1.0 component) dynamically generates the tree view at the client-side (it is implemented in pure Javascript).

The data in the tree nodes does exist in the DOM, but it's actually contained inside the *value* attribute of an *input* HTML tag in a comma-separated format. I'm guessing that this is what is returned from the server, then it's up to the client-side IE Web control to render the TreeView based on this. I'm assuming much of this knowledge from what I can see in the source code because I can't find any other documentation online for this web control, probably because it is so old.

I am currently looking at the feasibility of replacing the IE Web Control with the ASP.NET 2.0 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Treeview. I experimented a little with this and it seems that the HTML is generated server-side this time, instead of at the client-side, and so the generated HTML **is** available in the HTML DOM for the page, and thus I can select the tree nodes and do what I want with them!

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is OK **in IE**, but `.css()` for some reason is not available for that object.
But `.attr()` works fine:

```
alert($("tvns\\:treeview").html());
$("tvns\\:treeview").attr("style", "color: red;");
```

My [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3eBN5/4/).

**upd. better pure js solution:**

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("tvns:treeview");
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
{
    els[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3eBN5/8/)

Comment: Hi Enam, the css function worked fine for me for coloring a <div> element elsewhere on the page (using a class selector) in IE8 (I forgot to mention that the browser I'm using is IE8 Compatibility Mode with IE7 Standards document mode). I'll try selecting the element using javascript, but I need the JQuery selector as I'm trying to make the tree nodes draggable with JQuery UI - $("tvns\\treeview").draggable(). The reason I'm changing the CSS is just to see if I have the right selector.

Comment: So your post helps me see that my selector is correct, so the issue must be with the JQuery Draggable API. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I just tested, and the tree node color fails to change! It's still seems to be failing to select the treenode, despite the selector apparently being correct! Any ideas what other issues there could be?

Comment: In the IE Debugging Tools, I can see the nodes in the 'Script' tab, they are definitely there, but nothing changes in the nodes when applying CSS or adding the JQ Draggable functionality.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher there is a misprint in selector $("tvns\\treeview") in a comment above - colon is missed.

Comment: Just a typo in the comment box, I've verified my actual code and the selector is still $("tvns\\:treeview")

Comment: the css() works for a div() element. I also tried the attr() one though, and still it did not apply the CSS.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher no ideas.

Comment: I tried using pure Javascript and on debugging I can see that no nodes are found by the selector. I'll try with two backspaces like it's done for the JQuery selectors.

Comment: Wait a sec, in your question i see that the TreeView tag is "ciswc:TreeView" and the Treenode tag is "tvns:treenode". There are no "tvns:TreeView" tags.

Comment: I should explain that in the code the TreeView appears as "ciswc:TreeView", but in the code which is generated that I can see in the IE Developer Tools on running the application, it appears as <tvns:treeview>, and the nodes appear also as <tvns:treenode>. I'm not sure really sure why. The TreeView control is as far as I'm aware a really old IE Web Control that appeared to come with a much older ASP.NET version.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with the slashes inside the selector. You can try adding a dummy attribute to your tree nodes like "data-treenode" on each node.
Example (I dont have ie8, tested on ie11 with ie7 user agent):

```
<tvns:treenode Expanded="True" data-treenode="true" Selected="true" NavigateUrl="#"  NodeData="0">
        New Entity:
</tvns:treenode>

$("[data-treenode]").css("color", "red");

// another solution
$("[NavigateUrl][NodeData]").css("color", "red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FdgR4/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the creation of attributes on the tree nodes though, as it is generated using an IE Web Control (a really old component).

Comment: (Updated my answer) Then use something like
$("[NavigateUrl][NodeData]").css("color", "red");